# Failed to resolve dependency conciseclock

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Actually, it worked but I did not understand and I get an error. How can I fix it?

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.:conciseclock:0-SNAPSHOT'
           testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{ url 'https://dl.bintray.com/spark/maven' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        mavenCentral()

    }
}

task customClean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.:conciseclock:0-SNAPSHOT.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>
> Error(37,13) Failed to resolve: com.:conciseclock:0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

Try with `compile 'com.tomduan.conciseclock:library:0.2.2'`
Anyway, where did you get this snapshot, because it looks like you are using custom repository manager, not official [git](https://github.com/zurnacibatuhan/conciseclock).

Comment: @Lewis I think it's better to go once again to this web site and get link again. But while link creation proccess notice one thing. There should be some checkbox or param like `snapshot` or `release`. The way you have used it's SNAPSHOT and usually people use it for debug. For permanent use you should do release build.
And for custom repository you should have some custom repository, it should be `maven{ url 'https://dl.bintray.com/spark/maven' }` I think, just check if it's correct url. Release version should be included like `compile 'com.github.zurnacibatuhan:conciseclock:0#version.code'`

Comment: the proper version would be   `compile 'com.github.zurnacibatuhan:conciseclock:-633228b27e-1'`
And no, it won't be a problem

Comment: @Lewis, it doesn't matter actually, just for release applications it's better to use release (in case if you are using 3rd party's lib) because snapshot usually used by developers to try lib in real examples and test some features. It could be unstable.

Answer (score 0):

easy there is no library on this dependences

> com.github.zurnacibatuhan:conciseclock:0-SNAPSHOT

or i recommend to check library version so there is no number version as

> 0-SNAPSHOT

or replace with this line

> compile 'com.tomduan.conciseclock:library:0.2.2'

Comment: try to download project and insert it as new module then you will can use project take a look to this link https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Answer (score 0):

you are using `25.3.1` version in your dependencies.it means you should first add this to your project gradle repositories like this

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven{ url 'https://dl.bintray.com/spark/maven' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
}
```

add line

> maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}

after that you should replace this line:

> compile 'com.github.zurnacibatuhan:conciseclock:0-SNAPSHOT'

with this line:

> compile 'com.tomduan.conciseclock:library:0.2.2'